# Convert MPU6050 data into sound

Tags: accelerometer, mpu

I'm not sure this is the right place, but I've built a seismograph with an MPU6050. Now I'd like to convert the output of the MPU into sound. I really don't know where to start, someone has some ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not considering simply streaming the data out through a DAC (or PWM) and into an amplified speaker? What do you really want to hear?

Comment: that could be a solution, but the data of the MPU are uploaded to a web page and I'd like the user to listen to the sound from that page. Could I use your solution as well?

Comment: That's not an embedded question any more, if you have the data as numbers on a web page already. You can do anything you like with the data, like display it as a graph or play it as sound, but it has nothing to do with MPU6050 any more.

Comment: @EdwardIVRadical: Scale the data to be in the range -1 to 1.  Export to a .csv file.  Each line is one value from your MPU6050 values as a string ("-0.001".)  Use [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) to convert the .csv file to a .wav file using whatever sampling rate sounds good.  Alternatively, write a program to convert arbitrary numbers to .wav files using any programming language and/or libraries you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply with the measured momentary displacement the sample values in a data stream which plays your favourite earthquake music through a DA-converter. You store the music beforehand into the computer memory. As well you could have a slave device playing the music. The slave gets only the current sound volume from the seismograph. I guess the software only solution is possible without overloading the computer. But it's only a guess because I haven't a slightest idea what else there's going on as simultaneous tasks.

If you had enough computer power available you could also modulate the pitch of the music. That would simulate the wow and flutter caused by mechanically thumping a mechanical music player. Think about The Afternoon of a Faun (Debussy) which starts to stutter more or less violently.

To develop the idea you can fade in some less peaceful music, ideally composed algorithmically on the fly by using your own rule set how music should present seismic happenings.

Algorithmic composition on the fly can be too big task for a practical engineer. But you can rely on the talent of skilled musicians. There's many orchestras struggling due the lack of gigs due the corona. You could help one, say London Philharmonics by dividing it  to three 8 hour shifts. Every musician in the work has a simple sheet which contains "silence when the stick doesn't move and ad lib when the stick moves, but obey the conducted dynamics." The stick is a big projected image of your seismograph needle. I guess this job would inspire them to create collectively something which well fits into earthquakes.